# Why does S have to be const in this code?

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't the below code compile? It says that `S` has to be `const` as one of the major errors.

```cpp
template <int S>
class Array 
{
    int size;
    int items [S];

public:
Array(void) :size(S){}
};

void main()
{
    int  S= 30;
    Array <5+S> array;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact text of the error message along with what compiler you're using to build it.

Comment: Template argument must be known at compile-time. Make S constexpr.

Comment: btw you don't really need the size member, or at least make it a static const

Comment: Because defining an instance of `Array<S+5>` requires `S+5` to be known at compile time.   `S` is a variable, so there is nothing preventing it from being changed between `int S = 30` and `Array<5+S>array`.   How would you like it if the code compiled as is, but failed to compile if you added a statement `S = 42;` before defining `array`?     Also, `main()` returns `int`, not `void` in standard C++.

Answer (score 7):

Nontype template parameters must be `constexpr`, i.e., they have to be known at compile time. Hence, `S` must be declared as `constexpr int`.